# Web API for creating *meaningful* placeholder text

Tags: c#

Anyone know of a web api that returns understandable (i.e. NOT lorem ipsum) text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the Wikipedia API for this.

Comment: ahh never though of that, but it is a nice idea, do you know if it returns html markup or just text?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this:

- http://www.blindtextgenerator.com/lorem-ipsum

This will generate meaningful text as well as lorem ipsum :-) I hope you like it.

Also if you accept my apologies up front you can use F**KLorem.com:

- http://fucklorem.com/

Comment: f**klorem has a humorous name, but unfortunately no api, neither does blintextgenerator, thx anyway

Comment: You're right, Sorry for that! but F**KLoren will show you random text every time you load the page, so you can parse content and capture text. Also as RedFilter recommend you can use WikiPedia and I recommend to use: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Randompage (Sample Implementation: http://e-junkie-chronicles.blogspot.com/2011/11/quickly-load-sample-data-into.html)

Answer (score 1):

Samuel Jackson Motherf*#*ing placeholder text Motherf*#*#r! http://slipsum.com/